# Why does brushless motors heat up?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, heat-engine

I would like to know what makes a brushless motor heat up. I'm so aware of the problems generating the high temperetature such as wires contact problems or over loaded motors. I want to know what makes a normal motor in normal conditions get warm, is it related to Joule effect?

Comment: I am wondering, would this question find a better home in Engineering SE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an electric motor the current flows through wires with a finite resistance. Thus you get Joule heating. Furthermore, depending on the design of the motor, you can have electric [eddy currents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eddy_current) induced by the changing magnetic field in any conducting material. This also produces heat.